# Returning an int whenusing webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive

Tags: java, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm using Spring WebServiceTemplate class to to create and instantiate a request object of a JAXB generated class, call the marshallSendAndReceive method with it and then to cast the response object to an object of the JAXB generated response class.

This is working fine when returning the XML Objects of the JAXB generated response class (with Select Query) but now I want to execute a Delete query and just want to return the number of rows deleted. But I'm not sure how to achieve this!!

Do I need to convert that int return value into an XML object by using the following in the schema.xsd:

```
    <xs:element name="DelResponse" type="xs:integer"/>
```

OR
Is there another way of achieving the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to convert that int return value into an XML object

Yes.  All web service messages are encoded as XML, so you need to find a way of representing everything in XML, even if it's just a plain integer.

If you want something simpler, then SOAP/Spring-WS/JAXB isn't really the tool for the job.

Comment: Unfortunately I have 3 'Select' queries returning objects and therefore I'm just following the same setup for the delete statement as well rather than adopt a different approach. Could you please let me know a simple way of representing an Int value in XML.